# Vue not showing categories after fetch it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, fetch-api

I need some help with Vue rendering.
I'm making Vue-Wordpress app, and I'm trying to get a list of categories for each post. Categories of every post backed from WP API as id of it. I'm transfer categories ID as props in child element (prop "cats") and try to render it after fetching name. But on front-end I'm not see anything (in Vue dashboard I got list of categories names, sorry I can't post image with it).

```
 <template>
  <div class="bg-white border rounded border-black border-collapse">
    <h2 class="font-bold text-xl p-2 hover:text-gray-600 cursor-pointer">{{ title }}</h2>
    <div
      class="w-full h-48 bg-cover bg-center"
      :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')' }"
    ></div>
    <div class="px-4 py-2">
      <p class="text-gray-700 h-40 text-base" v-html="content"></p>
      <div>
        <span
          v-for="(val, index) in categories"
          :key="index"
          class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2"
        >{{val}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["title", "content", "image", "cats"],
  data() {
    return {
      categories: {}
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getAll();
  },
  methods: {
    getAll: function() {
      this.$props.cats.forEach(r => this.getCatName(r));
    },
    getCatName: function(id) {
      fetch(`http://rest-api.local/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/${id}`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(res => (this.categories[id] = res.name));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [reactivity caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), so you should use `this.$set` function :

```
 .then(res => (this.$set(this.categories,id,res.name)));
```

and the `id` property should be declared :

```
 data() {
    return {
      categories: {
       id:null
       }
    };
  },
```